# Rx - unsubscribing from events

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an INotifyPropertyChanged object, Foo. I turn Foo into an observable stream of events using Rx's FromEvent method:

```
var myFoo = new Foo();
var eventStream = Observable.FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(myFoo, "PropertyChanged");
```

Now I want to listen for a particular property changed, and if .Progress == 100, unsubscribe:

```
eventStream
   .Where(e => myFoo.Progress == 100)
   .Subscribe(OnFooFinished);
```

How can I unsubscribe when Progress == 100? If I add a .Take(1) call after the .Where clause, would that automatically unsubscribe?

Comment: I've accepted Jon's answer below: adding a .Take(1) to the query will call OnCompleted, which calls Dispose automatically.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One option is to use return value of `Subscribe`:

```
IDisposable subscription = eventStream.Where(e => myFoo.Progress == 100)
                                      .Subscribe(OnFooFinished);

...

// Unsubscribe
subscription.Dispose();
```

I *suspect* that using `Take(1)` would indeed unsubscribe though, and it *may* be neater for you. Having looked at it a bit, I'm pretty sure this *would* unsubscribe, as it'll fire the "completed" message, which generally unsubscribes automatically. I don't have time to check this for sure at the moment, I'm afraid :(

Comment: I realize I could call Dispose. Unfortunately, I would need to call Dispose inside the OnFooFinished handler, which doesn't have a reference to the IDisposable. However, if Take(1) does the trick, that would be absolutely brilliant. I'm going to trust the almighty Skeet on this one. If it fails, I'll tell my team Skeet is to blame. :-)

Comment: @Judah: LOL. I'm sure that `OnFooFinished` won't be called again, at the very least. Assuming the actual unsubscription is important though, it would be worth checking that. I can look into it in a few hours, if that's any help.

Comment: Ah, you don't have to do the work for me. I'll check it out. Thanks though. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: This thread seems to suggest that yes, Dispose will be called automatically when OnCompleted is invoked, and that all subscribers will be automatically unsubscribed through this process: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/rx/thread/269cd22a-259c-4780-a2f5-94c77469eddd

Comment: @Judah: Well found - that does seem to confirm it, and it would certainly make sense.

Comment: All Rx operators use a wrapper to ensure that the dispose behavior is the same between an unsubscribe (Dispose), onCompleted and onError

Answer (score 20):

You could use the TakeWhile method:

```
eventStream.TakeWhile(e => myFoo.Progress != 100);
```

TakeWhile *will* dispose the underlying observable sequence when its predicate returns false, you will *not* have to call dispose manually.

Comment: Thanks. I need to invoke some function when myFoo.Progress == 100, though, so this doesn't quite work for my scenario. But thanks, I get the idea now.

Comment: @Judah - Markus' answer will allow you to do that; just call your method from the OnCompleted part of the subscriber.