# When observable created with Observable.FromEvent will be detached from event producer?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

UPDATE: found similar question: [Rx - unsubscribing from events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449834/rx-unsubscribing-from-events)

Given the code:

```
interface IBitmapCapturer {
    event EventHandler<EventArgs<RawBitmap>> Captured;
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}

public class Camera {
    IBitmapCapturer m_capturer;

    public RawBitmap CaptureBitmap() {
        IObservable<IEvent<EventArgs<RawBitmap>>> observable = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs<RawBitmap>>(
            handler => m_capturer.Captured += handler,
            handler => m_capturer.Captured -= handler);
        m_capturer.Start();
        IEvent<EventArgs<RawBitmap>> evn = observable.First();
        m_capturer.Stop();
        return evn.EventArgs.EventData;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here is capturing a shot from Camera but the only first one. IBitmapCapturer is some DirectShow-related stuff and doesn't provide a method to "make a shot", only generating events with bitmaps. So I'm using Reactive Extensions to take the first event and unsubscribe.
My doubts are about "observable.First()" line.

Do I understand correctly that after calling observable.First() my observable is detached from m_capturer (event producer)? If not then how can I make sure that there're no subscribers on m_capturer.Captured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework ensures that the `IDisposable` value returned from `Subscribe` is disposed of when the sequence completes or errors, and the `IDisposable` returned by `FromEvent` unsubscribes from the event.

Since `First` is a blocking implementation of `Take(1)`, the source sequence will be disposed after the first value is received (or after it throws an exception when the source is empty).

In short, you can be sure that the event handler is being removed after your call to `First` completes.

Comment: yeah, Subscribe creates subscription and it can't disposed, but not FromEvent's result. It's not a subscription, it's kind an adapter from c# event to IObservable (not an observer)..

Comment: I understand that, but disposing the return value of `FromEvent().Subscribe()` will still remove the subscription.

Comment: You can't use First here, precisely because as Richard says, it blocks: you're deadlocking yourself.

Comment: Paul, it's code from live project, there's no any deadlock. If you meant "blocks" not "deadlocks" then yes, it blocks - this' exactly what I need.

Comment: @PaulBetts - that would depend on what thread the event fires OnNext on.