# Unsubscribe from dynamic Observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm learning Rx-stuff and I've made a test app, which has a shared counter state and dynamically created counter widgets. Such as you can press add/remove buttons to spawn/destroy a new counter. It works fine, but I don't know how to correctly dispose removed counter widgets.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/saintcrawler/b2530d9ee798c172a369d6769a5673e7) is my source code.

One part of a problem is at line [77](https://gist.github.com/saintcrawler/b2530d9ee798c172a369d6769a5673e7#file-rx-test-cs-L77):

```
// update each counter's label
addCounterStream.Subscribe(x => {
    counterState.Subscribe(q => x.Counter = q.ToString()); // How can I unsubscribe later?
});
```

And the possible solution, I can think of, is to create a `Subject<IDisposable>` which will collect these subscriptions and then combine this stream with `removeCounterStream` and do unsibscribe.

But another part of a problem is at lines 40, 41:

```
var incFromWidget = addCounterStream.SelectMany(x => Observable.FromEventPattern(x, "Increment").Select(_ => 1));
var decFromWidget = addCounterStream.SelectMany(x => Observable.FromEventPattern(x, "Decrement").Select(_ => -1));
```

It merges click events from all dynamically created widgets. What will happen if I want to remove some widget? It will disappear from the form and so won't be able to produce new click events, but it can not be `GC`'ed, because it still hold references to click events (because of `FromEventPattern`).

That is a memory leak, am I right?

So, the question is how to correctly deal with Observables of objects that can be added/removed dynamically?

Comment: can't you simply dispose it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449834/rx-unsubscribing-from-events?rq=1

Comment: @pix I can not dispose it, because it will stop events from all widgets and I  need to dispose only widgets that are about to be removed (when clicking remove counter button). I can filter (or maybe GroupBy) events by particular widget (at lines 40, 41), but how can I dispose them if I never subscribes?  Because I subscribe only to `counterState` (which consists of these two). And then again, GroupBy is a buffering operation, which will lead to memory leak again.

Comment: Multiple nested subscriptions is usually a bad thing. You should be able to write the query so that `Subscribe` is only called once per subscribtion AND the returned `IDisposable` actually releases all the resources when called.

Answer (score 0):

While digging deeper into the problem, I found 3 possible solutions:

1. for that specific case I can use `Disposed` event of the control like this:

   ```
   var incsFromWidgets = addCounterStream
           .SelectMany(x => Observable.FromEventPattern(x, "Increment")
               .Select(_ => 1)
               .TakeUntil(Observable.FromEventPattern(x, "Disposed").Take(1)))
           .Publish();
   ```
2. actually it's generalization of the 1st method: I can make generic wrapper class with release semantics, like:

   ```
   class Wrapper<T> : IDisposable {
       public T Value { get; set; }
       public event EventHandler Disposed;        
   }
   ```
3. manual "hoisting" of the streams:

   ```
   // declare all streams
   IObservable<int> aStream = null;
   IObservable<bool> bStream = null;
   IObservable<MyWidget> cStream = null;

   // then compose it
   aStream = Observable.From(...).TakeUntil(bStream.Where(...));
   bStream = Observable.From(...).CombineLatest(aStream, ...);  // cyclic dependency
   ```

While the 3rd method may seem awful, it gives the great possibilities to combine streams in different ways, just need to be careful and do not create infinite recursions.

**EDIT:**
 Well, actually the 3rd method is not that simple, it will throw NullReferenceException even if streams are defined below. The proper implementation would be smth like:

```
        IConnectableObservable<int> a = null;
        IConnectableObservable<char> b = null;
        IConnectableObservable<bool> c = null;            

        a = Observable.Defer(() => b.Select(x => (int)x)).Publish();
        b = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Generate('A', x => x < 255, x => (char)(x + 1), x => x).TakeUntil(c)).Publish();
        c = Observable.Defer(() => a.SkipWhile(x => x < 70).Select(_ => true)).Publish();

        a.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"from a: {x}"));
        b.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"from b: {x}"));

        c.Connect();
        a.Connect();
        b.Connect();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```